# HAProxy basic configuration - defining primary backend

Tags: haproxy

Quite a simple question - looking to use HA Proxy to solve an issue with accessing primary or secondary servers. 
The ideal is a system where the proxy always directs users to the Primary unless 
1: the primary is not responding on a specified port or 
2: We tell the proxy to use the secondary
Would this be a case of using Round Robin with Weighting and assigning a maximum weight of 256 (?) to primary and a weight of 1 to secondary?
So in this case if Primary is inaccessible then secondary is used ?
And to tell the system which to use then we can simply swap the weighting or similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer! In your backend definition(s), you can mark server(s) as "backup", and HAProxy will only route requests to those server(s) if the non-backup server(s) are not available. From the [configuration manual](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#5.2-backup):

> When "backup" is present on a server line, the server is only used in
>   load balancing when all other non-backup servers are unavailable.
>   Requests coming with a persistence cookie referencing the server will
>   always be served though. By default, only the first operational backup
>   server is used, unless the "allbackups" option is set in the backend.
>   See also the "allbackups" option.